# Trapezoidal rule over interpolation of higher dimensional vectors

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, approximation, approximate-integration

According to a [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule) and [mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Newton-CotesFormulas.html), the trapezoidal rule is:

$$
\int_a^b f(x)\,dx \approx h\left[\frac{f(a) + f(b)}{2} \right],
$$

where $h = (b-a)$.

If you apply this rule to a function $f(\mathbf{q})$ of a linear interpolation over an $n$-dimensional vector from $\mathbf{q}_1$ to $\mathbf{q}_2$ (in $\mathbb{R}^n$), i.e.,
$$
\int_0^1 f(\mathbf{q}_1+x(\mathbf{q}_2-\mathbf{q}_1)) \, dx,
$$
does it still hold that $h=(b-a)=1$?  Or is it instead in the dimensionality of the interpolation, thus $h=\|\mathbf{q}_2-\mathbf{q}_1\|$?  Or is it something else altogether?

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int_0^1 f({\vec q_1}+x({\vec q_2-\vec q_1}))dx=\frac{f_0({\vec q_1}+x({\vec q_2-\vec q_1}))}{x}|_0^1$$
where $\int f(x)=f_0(x)$
So,
$$I=f_0({\vec q_2})-f_0({\vec q_1})=\int_{\vec q_1}^{\vec q_2}f(x)dx\approx g({\vec q_2-\vec  q_1})\left[\frac{f({\vec q_1})+f({\vec q_2})}{2}\right]$$
If $f({\vec v})=f(|{\vec v}|)$ or simply if f is a scalar then $g({\vec v})=|v|$
If not then $g({\vec v})=v$

Comment: Thanks Aditya, this helps, but I'm still unclear on what $h$ or, now $g(\mathbf{q})$ is.  At least I get that the integral is effected by the interpolation on the vector.  If specifically, $f(\mathbf{q}) = \| \mathbf{q} - \mathbf{q}_{\mathrm{fixed}} \|$ (L2 distance to a fixed point), what is $h$ and/or $g(\mathbf{q})$?